# SequelizeEagerLoadingError : Sequelize model association when using include for query not working

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I auto generated my sequelize models from an already existing database, so the associations were done automatically with all theirs alias, Now i want to do eager loading on the database by joining tables on query but am get errors, i have tried all manner of patterns.

Here is the error
[There Sequelize error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Dkc.png)

i keep having that error on every of the trial below

Here is the  code

```
const db = require('../../../database/models/index');

module.exports =  async function(parents, args) {

  let userRecord = await db.user.findAll({
  // db is a reference to the models instancs
  
    include:  db.userDetail, // this the actual models
 
  // include:  ["user_details_user_detail"], // this is the alias gotting for models association
  // include:  "user_detail", // this is the alias gotting for models association
  // include: { 
  //   model:db.userDetail
  // }
})
    if(!userRecord){
      throw new Error('No record foudn')
    }
    return{
      message:'successfull'
    }
      
}
```

[my actual code with the include (eager loading)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQtQt.png)

And here are the model definitions for the user and userDetail respectively

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    user_details: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'user_details',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    country: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'country',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    state: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'state',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    lga: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'lga',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    ward: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    polling_unit: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    user_type: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    lga_of_origin: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'lga',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    state_of_origin: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'state',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    update_details: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    user_bio_added: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'user',
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "user_details",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "user_details" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "state",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "state" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "country",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "country" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "lga",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "lga" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "ward",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "ward" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "polling_unit",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "polling_unit" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "user_type",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "user_type" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "state_of_origin",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "state_of_origin" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "lga_of_origin",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "lga_of_origin" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

And for the userDetails

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('userDetail', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    },
    last_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: "email"
    },
    short: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    permanent_home_address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(300),
      allowNull: false
    },
    date_of_birth: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true
    },
    other_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'user_details',
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "email",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "email" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

and their association on a different file

```
var _user = require("./user");
var _userDetail = require("./userDetail");
function initModels(sequelize) {
  var user = _user(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var userDetail = _userDetail(sequelize, DataTypes);

user.belongsTo(userDetail, { as: "user_details_user_detail", foreignKey: "user_details"});
  userDetail.hasMany(user, { as: "users", foreignKey: "user_details"});

}
```

pictures
[The user and user Detail model association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgxE8.png)

Comment: Please include all screenshoted code pieces as code blocks in the post

Comment: And make sure you have registered associations in `user` model instance looking at `associations` prop

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what i was doing wrong.
first, i scaffolded my project with [sequelize cli command](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/) which gives me predefined configurations such as my models, migrations and seeders. as this

[the sequelize scaffold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbee5.png)

There was a need to use an already existing database and not to write my models all by myself, so i [auto generated](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto)  my models and with another extra use for the definition of my model associations. now my model file look as so
[my models folder after auto generation of the models from a db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmHQV.png)

my index file from sequelize cli scaffold, all the associations are configured suppose i am to write my  models and the corresponding association by my self

***models/index.js***

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const process = require('process');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];
const db = {};
let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
   
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
module.exports = db;
```

And i have my models generated from an aready existing database as such

***models/user.js***

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    user_details: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'user_details',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    country: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'country',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    state: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'state',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    lga: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'lga',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    ward: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    polling_unit: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    user_type: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    lga_of_origin: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'lga',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    state_of_origin: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'state',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    update_details: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    user_bio_added: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'user',
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "user_details",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "user_details_id" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "state",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "state" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "country",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "country" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "lga",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "lga" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "ward",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "ward" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "polling_unit",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "polling_unit" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "user_type",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "user_type" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "state_of_origin",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "state_of_origin" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "lga_of_origin",
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "lga_of_origin" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

And the for userDetails model

***models/userDetail.js***

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('userDetail', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    },
    last_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: "email"
    },
    short: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    permanent_home_address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(300),
      allowNull: false
    },
    date_of_birth: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: true
    },
    other_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'user_details',
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "email",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "email" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

And now i have file also auto generated, that defines the associations for this models as so

***models/init.models.js***

```
var DataTypes = require("sequelize").DataTypes;
var _user = require("./user");
var _userDetail = require("./userDetail");


function initModels(sequelize) {

  var user = _user(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var userDetail = _userDetail(sequelize, DataTypes);

  user.belongsTo(userDetail, { as: "user_details_user_detail", foreignKey: "user_details"});
  userDetail.hasMany(user, { as: "users", foreignKey: "user_details"});
  return {
    user,
    userDetail,
   
  };
}
module.exports = initModels;
module.exports.initModels = initModels;
module.exports.default = initModels;
```

**Now the issues occured because i was using the model configuration file only without making reference to the file where the association between the model is define, since the CLI model configuration assume that each of the model file exported will have the association defined along side it, but in my case, the entire models association was  abstracted out of the  model definition file is exported as a function**

[Cli sequelize instance configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViSvG.png)

**When i am using it, i just called the model without it association file definition, cus the association was not define in the model file as oppose to how the instance configuration assumed**

[Using it the model wrongly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRMRi.png)

**This was how i solved this the controller/mutation i am using it**

```
const db = require('../../../database/models/index');
const initModels = require('../../../database/models/init-models');
let model = initModels(db.sequelize)

module.exports =  async function(parents, args) {

  let userRecord = await model.user.findAll({
  include: "user_details_user_detail"
})

if(!userRecord){
  throw new Error('user not found')
}
console.log("it worked")
}
```

**I  had to also modify the models/index.js file to remove the association difined in it as so**

***models/index.js***

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const process = require('process');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];
const db = {};
let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
module.exports = db;
```

**thanks you guys.**